# Launcher app and the home key not consistant

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

I have been building a launcher app with many activities.  I want the home button to always bring the user back to the mainActivity, when the home key is pressed and they have my app set as the default launcher.  This works 90% of the time, but after some time the home key eventually stops working.. it registers the user's press but doesn't return them to the mainactivity any more.  What causes this has evaded me.. we have tried for months to recreate the bug with some consistency but to no avail.  We can't figure out what causes it to stop working..  below is my manifest.  i am wondering if i am missing some sort of flag or something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|uiMode"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="4.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LCInStore2Activity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|uiMode"
        android:label="Main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Authenticate"
        android:label="Authenticate"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.AUTHENTICATE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Settings"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.SETTINGS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CustomerHome"
        android:label="CustomerHome"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CUSTOMERHOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CustomWebView"
        android:label="CustomWebView"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CUSTOMWEBVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CustomCamera"
        android:label="CustomCamera"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CUSTOMCAMERA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FavoritesCustomer"
        android:label="FavoritesCustomer"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.FAVORITESCUSTOMER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FavoritesAssociate"
        android:label="FavoritesAssociate"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.FAVORITESASSOCIATE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Browser"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="Browser"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >

        <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.BROWSER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.VideoViewer"
        android:label="Video Viewer"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.VIDEOVIEWER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GalleryOneUp"
        android:label="GalleryOneUp"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.GALLERYONEUP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GalleryFourUp"
        android:label="GalleryFourUp"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.GALLERYFOURUP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GeneralRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="GeneralRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.GeneralRX" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SunglassRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="SunglassRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.SunglassRX" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ComputerRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="ComputerRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.ComputerRX" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.NightGlassesRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="NightGlassesRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.NightGlassesRX" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActiveRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="ActiveRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.ActiveRX" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SafetyRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="SafetyRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.SafetyRx" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ContactRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="ContactRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.ContactRx" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SettingsRx"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:label="SettingsRx"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.SettingsRX" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SettingsReceiver" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CEETraining"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ceetraining"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.CeeTraining" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.BrandTraining"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brand_training"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.BrandTraining" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LensTraining"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lens_training"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.LensTraining" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MakeAbility"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_makeability"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.Makeability" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MakeabilityResults"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_makeability_results"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.activities.Makeabilityresults" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: For clarification.  I assume that you are seeing the key events for the home button in logcat (it registers the user's press)?  How do you know the intent is not getting to your app?  I assume nothing in onResume()

Comment: To clarify we are running on 4.0.4 samsung tablets.. i know the home key is fireing because it brings up the window asking which launcher we want (our app being in the list)  but it doesn't return to the main activity..

Comment: it doesn't return to the main activity when the user selects your app from the list of available launchers?

Comment: not all the time no!  when we first install the app it most of the time performs perfect for a while.. like a day roughly, but then stops behaving as expected.. some times it doesnt work right after install.. and we uninstall, and reinstall and it works fine.. again.. only for a limited time..  another note is that we can only recreate this bug on a signed apk.. the bug, NEVER happens when using a debug version of the app..

Comment: Is your main activity getting anything in onNewIntent when you select your app to be launched when the home key is pressed?

Comment: If your main activity is already running but isn't in the foreground, when the system sends you a HOME intent, it should hit `onNewIntent` instead of `onCreate`.  You might need to set your main activity to `launchMode="singleTask"` though which sounds like what you need to do anyway.

Comment: im going to add that method override now to my main activity and try to recreate the bug.. what should i put in that method to insure mainactivty is brought foward?

Comment: Nothing specific.  Just whatever sort of initialization you normally do when the activity is created.  Make sure to add the launchMode line into your manifest as that's what's going to bring your activity to the front.

Comment: which launchmode?  singleTop?  and on all activities or just my main

Comment: i added android:launchMode="singleTop" and added the following code to my acivity:

 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        
            Log.v("LCInStore2Activity", "***************************************** on intent called");
       
    }

Comment: but the onIntent doesn't seem to get called

Comment: singleTask, not singleTop.  See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem you're having can be solved by making your Home replacement's main activity a single task.

To do that you would add the following line to your manifest as part of the main activity: `launchMode="singleTask"`  A description of what this does can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

Now whenever your app receives a home key press event and the app isn't running, it'll start a new instance with `onCreate`.  If the app is already running in the foreground or in a suspended state, `onNewIntent` will be called in your main activity and it will be brought to the front.

Comment: This is always firing the onIntent called from outside the app.. thanks.. will let you know if it fixes the bug.. its hard to say as the bug comes out of no where

Comment: Thanks @MCeley. I too had the same problem.Adding launch mode as "singleTask" worked.